# Puedo establecer una app en android como default para abrir links con comandos adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, adb

Necesito correr unos tests que como precondicion necesitan una instalacion fresca de la aplicacion, no ejecutarla, dirigirme a un link en el navegador y en el tocar el boton "abrir en la app".

Como estoy probando con una version alpha de la app, esta no trae como predeterminado abrir los links relacionados con esas paginas.
Estos tests necesito ejecutarlos en distintos dispositivos, por lo que realizar esta configuracion interactuando con la UI no es una buena aproximacion...

Mi pregunta es, es posible poder establecer una app como predeterminada para que se abra con determinados links utilizando comandos adb?

Lo que intento replicar a traves de adb es lo siguiente:
Configuracion > Apps > Configuracion de la app > Establecer como predeterminada > Abrir links permitidos (habilitar)

Hasta ahora intente corriendo `adb shell pm set-app-links --package "package.de.app" 1 all` para setear todos los links en supported, pero creo que el comando no es el que busco ni tampoco me funciona

Gracias!

Comment: el titulo tambien!!!!

Comment: Algo como [esto](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246359)?

Comment: Si se puede, agrega lo que trataste por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar alguno de las siguientes opciones:

- Utilizando comandos de adb

> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d

Por ejemplo, digamos que tu app tiene la siguiente activity declarado en el manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Entonces vas a poder ejecutar algo como

> adb shell am start
> -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
> -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android

Referencia: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

- Otra opción es utilizar el asistente de android Studio para deeplinks y otras cosas adicionales.

Referencia: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

- Una tercera opción ( la más acercada hacia un test ) es crear un archivo html con el deeplink hacia tu aplicacion. Guardas ese archivo html en tu device. Abres el archivo html desde tu device y haces click en el link para abrir tu aplicación.

Ejemplo:

```
<html>
     .....    
     <a href="example://gizmos">Open my app from browser</a>
     .....
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!
En este caso, estoy buscando una alternativa a deeplinking, debido a que no se alinea a los requerimientos del test que quiero ejecutar.
El proposito de establecer la app como default para abrir links es para poder navegar al link utilizando un navegador, interactuar con un boton y que este me ejecute la app en lugar de enviarme al play store para descargar una app que tenga support con este sitio.